# Recursive function doesn't return the value of the cancel condition

Tags: c, if-statement, return-value

I have a recursive function that simulates a Bashni-Game (kind of checkers game). My function gets the field and my colour. It checks if the game is over, which is the cancel condition of my recursion. For -1 it means the game isnt over so it calls itself recursively with changed colour and the new gameboard. If the game is over it either returns 0 or 1.

```
int simulate(int myColour, char field[WIDTH][HEIGTH][MAX_TOWER_LENGTH]){
    int cancel = checkForEndOfGame(field); 
    //int returnValue=50;
    struct moveArray moves;
    memset(&moves, 0, sizeof(moves)); 
    printf("DEBUG: CANCEL-Value: %i\n", cancel);
    if(cancel==-1){
        moves=calculatePossibleMoves(moves, field, myColour);
        int indexMove = rand() % moves.count;
        makeMove(field, moves.moves[indexMove]);
        printGameboard(field);
        int colourChange;
        if(myColour==WHITE){
            colourChange=BLACK;
        } else colourChange=WHITE;
        simulate(colourChange, field);
    }
    if(cancel==0){
        printGameboard(field);
        return 1;
    }
    if(cancel==1){
        printGameboard(field);
        return 0;
    }
    return 13;
}
```

Even if cancel has the value 1 (what means I should get the return 0), my function returns 13.
I put the return 13 just because otherwise my compiler (gcc) gives my the error:

```
error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths
      [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: Since the compiler can't check `checkForEndOfGame`, it must assume that _any_ `int` value can be returned. For example, if it returned `2`, _none_ of your `if` would be true. So, the control would go to the bottom of the function. The compiler realizes that there is no `return` for this control path, so it flags it. That's why you _need_ it.

Comment: Hint: when `cancel == -1`, what will `simulate()` return?

Comment: but even if i put a: else return 12; it wont compile

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: but isnt that the way recursion works, that it will get to the cancel Condition and returns 0 or 1 in the end?

Comment: In this code path it calls `simulate()`.  When the recursive call to `simulate()` returns, execution continues.  The value of `cancel` in this instance of `simulate()` hasn't changed and is still `-1`, so neither of the remaining `if` blocks execute, and we fall through to the `return 13` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive call doesn't make any attempt to pass the cancel reason through to the caller. You seem to expect this to happen somehow automatically, but it won't. Each recursive call of `simulate` has its own local variables -- crucially, `cancel` -- so after the recursive call returns, the local value of `cancel` will be unchanged (and still -1) and so 13 will be returned.

What you probably wanted to do was to just pass through the return value, making the recursive call a tail-call:

```
 return simulate(colourChange, field);
```